# how to make the onesignal push notification url open in the same android web view

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, onesignal

i create and android webview to show my website and i connect onesignal push notification to it but every time i send a url with push notification it ask me to view it on google chrome or other browser not my android web view

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    OneSignal.startInit(this)
            .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
            .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
            .init();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_psalms);
```

Comment: are you able to do this or not ? Please update. If yes then please post a solution.. Thanks